# C++ Dll Boundaries Using an Abstract Interface -> smart pointer in header? calling delete?

Tags: c++, dll

I read through [this excellent summary](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL) about dll boundaries in c++.

I wrote an example implementation in a single project.

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include "Interface.hpp"

typedef std::shared_ptr<Interface> IPTR;

int main()
{
    IPTR ptr = std::shared_ptr<Interface>(MakeInterface(), std::mem_fn(&Interface::Release));
    std::cout << ptr->Foo(4) << "\n";
}
```

`Interface.hpp`

```
#define MyAPI /*export/import*/
#define APIENTRY __stdcall

struct MyAPI Interface
{
    virtual int Foo(int n) = 0;
    virtual void Release() = 0;
};

extern "C" MyAPI Interface* APIENTRY MakeInterface();
```

`Interface.cpp`

```
#include "Interface.hpp"

struct InterfaceImpl : Interface
{
    virtual int Foo(int n){ return n; }
    virtual void Release(){ delete this; }
};

extern "C" MyAPI Interface* APIENTRY MakeInterface()
{
    return new InterfaceImpl{};
}
```

My questions are

- Can I move the smart pointer declaration into the header without running into C++ dll issues?
- Is it correct to call `delete this` in the Release method?

Comment: @Dan I see your point and you instantly knew what I was getting at :)

Comment: Ofc you can. You can even export shared_ptr's and STL containers, providing that the client uses the same CRT and STL version. If you want to get rid of these problems, use COM which is a binary interface specification. The downside is that your types have to be throttled back to C types (e.g. arrays).

Comment: You dont have to use COM. Just use standard layout types that are not depended on runtime libraries or encapsulate runtime dependencies or non standard layout types.

Comment: If you always compile your application and DLL with the same compiler, you don't need to worry about calling conventions, interfaces and such. If you don't then none of this will help, you need much stronger isolation like COM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) No.

```
extern "C" MyAPI Interface* APIENTRY MakeInterface()
{
    return new InterfaceImpl{};
}
```

This `new` is used from the dll-runtime and can be incompatible with `new` from the executable. Destroying the object by `delete` (executable) may not work due to different memory managers. Rule of thumb: If you provide a create/make-function (factory) then you should provide a destroy/free/delete function. Your `Release`-method will work but is on a different abstraction level than `MakeInterface`. Rule of 2 thumbs: Export independent standard layout types in combination with pimpl.

2.) Yes.

Comment: My impression of the question is that both MakeInterface and the Release method are in the DLL, and thus using the same memory manager.  In general, you do have to be very aware about the chance of allocating in one module and deallocating in another.  (It commonly happens when one operation or the other in is the header file and thus could be inlined into either module.)  It's one of the reasons Microsoft suggests relying on the DLL runtime instead of statically linking to the runtime libraries.

Comment: Yes they are in the same DLL. Different abstraction levels: free function vs. member function. I would prefer free functions for creation and deletion. The class should have a "private" constructor and destruction. Your second point: I design most of my DLL interfaces for static runtime linking (if possible). It means more than just than setting a compiler flag.

Answer (score 1):

The Method that you use is what we use at job at it works.
One thing you must pay attention is to pass only C data type of at most pod as argument of your interface. 
If you didn't you may incur with memory issue. 
For example if you define a function in your interface with a string argument:

```
struct Mapi Interface
{
   void wrong(string& a_string)=0
};
```

you may have trouble if you compile the client and dll with a different STL version (Think a new version of dll, recompiled vith vs2015 but the client remain old, compiled with vs6).

In this example I pass a ref to string. The initial buffer of the string is allocated by the client.

Now in the dll you assign a new value to a_string, a value big enough to need reallocation. 
In this way you free the initial buffer inside dll context. If the heap manager was different (different crt) you have memory issue

Comment: You can use static linking for your runtime within the DLL.

Comment: it is not a question of static linking. Who allocates memory must be that frees it unless you share the same c++ runtime.